# What are the fundamental violations in $\rm n \to p+e^-$?

Tags: particle-physics, conservation-laws, radiation, neutrinos

When the neutrino was postulated to complete the decay:

$$\rm n \to p+e^-+\bar{\nu}_e$$

if I'm not wrong, there was still not such a thing as lepton number violation. I know that the kinematic observed spectrum of the decay was only compatible with an additional particle taking part of the energy released in the decay, but is there any other fundamental violation taking place in this decay if the neutrino is not included?

Comment: I've deleted some pseudo-answers and related comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just energy and momentum conservation. To be clear, the process $\rm n\to p+e^-$ could conserve momentum in principle, but the actual observed decays of the neutron violate momentum conservation if you ignore the neutrino.

Comment: You mean the conservation of the momentum quadri-vector, right?

Comment: Sort of. The conservation of four-momentum implies both energy conservation and three-momentum conservation. This decay violates *both*, not just one.

Comment: but isn't the total four-momentum the ones that needs to be conserved?

Comment: No, each component is conserved *separately*. Energy is conserved, as is momentum in the x-direction, momentum in the y-direction, and momentum in the z-direction.

Comment: It does not conserve spin.  This is why the neutrino is added: the LHS has an odd half-spin, while the RHS is even.  This is one of the things that brought down the hydrogen theory.

Comment: It is worth looking at [Pauli's "radioactive ladies and gentlemen" letter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/21814/dear-radioactive-ladies-and-gentlemen-letter-by-wolfgang-pauli). Horse's mouth and all that.